# variable from ngRepeat doesn't work inside ngClick

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have no idea what i'm doing wrong. App is getting object from server via REST, and then list it in table. Everything looks pretty nice, but variables in ngClick argument doesn't compile so it makes some troubles.

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces" id="workspace_{[{workspace.id}]}">
    <td>{[{ workspace.name }]}</td>
    <td>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="renameWorkspace(workspace.id)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteWorkspace(workspace.id)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Outputs:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces" id="workspace_1" class="ng-scope">
    <td class="ng-binding">Work12</td>
    <td>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="renameWorkspace(workspace.id)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteWorkspace(workspace.id)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces" id="workspace_2" class="ng-scope">
    <td class="ng-binding">Private43243</td>
    <td>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="renameWorkspace(workspace.id)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteWorkspace(workspace.id)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces" id="workspace_3" class="ng-scope">
    <td class="ng-binding">iuytre</td>
    <td>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="renameWorkspace(workspace.id)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteWorkspace(workspace.id)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Angular (1.5.5):

```
var cerber = angular.module('cerber', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngCookies']);

cerber.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');

  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl : templatesUrlPrefix + 'group',
    controller  : 'mainController'
  })
  [...]
  .otherwise({redirectTo : '/'});

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
});

cerber.controller('mainController', function($scope, $cookies, $location, $http, $route, $compile, GroupService, InstanceService, WorkspaceService) {
$scope.manageWorkspaces = function(){
  $http({
    url: responsesUrlPrefix + 'get-workspaces',
    method: "GET",
    params: {}
  })
  .then(function(response){
    $scope.workspaces = response.data;
    angular.element('.workspaces-manage-modal').modal('show');
  });
}
```

Response:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Work12","icon":"fa-briefcase","user_id":1,"created_at":"2016-05-16 21:01:22","updated_at":"2016-05-28 23:02:55"},{"id":2,"name":"Private43243","icon":"fa-user","user_id":1,"created_at":"2016-05-16 21:01:22","updated_at":"2016-05-28 23:02:08"},{"id":3,"name":"iuytre","icon":"fa-user","user_id":1,"created_at":"2016-05-28 23:51:23","updated_at":"2016-05-28 23:51:23"},{"id":4,"name":"iuytre","icon":"fa-user","user_id":1,"created_at":"2016-05-28 23:51:33","updated_at":"2016-05-28 23:51:33"}]
```

Comment: *"variables in ngClick argument doesn't compile so it makes some troubles"* - what troubles? It's not supposed to compile and output will be `ng-click="deleteWorkspace(workspace.id)"`, how it should be.

Comment: Your functions: renameWorkspace, deleteWorkspace is in your service WorkspaceService ?

Comment: @NotBad4U in MainController `$scope.deleteWorkspace = function(workspaceId)`

Comment: @dfsq so you are saing these functions should work even if in DOM structure i can see name of variable not value?

Comment: You seem to be confused by how Angular works and what it does with those attributes. `ng-click` accepts dynamic expressions that are parsed and evaluated at runtime by framework.

Answer (score 0):

Angular JS will not show you the arguments you are passing in the DOM but will give you the right output in the controller.

You can easily write functions in your main controller which accepts the argument as:

```
$scope.renameWorkspace = function(workSpaceId){
    console.log(workSpaceId);
};

$scope.deleteWorkspace = function(workSpaceId){
    console.log(workSpaceId);
}
```

Comment: He has already written these functions in his MainCtrl. "@NotBad4U in MainController $scope.deleteWorkspace = function(workspaceId"